# Palabra o frase en español para "bleach stain"

Tags: ropa

Cuando se habla de ropa, a veces una parte de la ropa es rosa claro o amarillo claro porque se usó hipoclorito de calcio y agua para lavar la ropa. ¿Cuál es la frase o palabra en español para la marca visible en la ropa?

[image: a photograph of a bleach stain]

Comment: bleach in Spanish is lejía.

Answer (score 2):

For "bleach stain", in the Southern cone of South America we use "mancha de lavandina".

In Spain, I guess they call it "mancha de lejía".

Comment: Good guess :-) +1 to "Mancha de lejía" in Spain.

Comment: We don't say southern cone in English. You can say southern end or tip of LA.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Cone

Comment: I don't care what Wikipedia says. It just isn't used to refer to **all the Spanish-speaking countries in LA and the ones in Central America and the Caribbean** and that usually includes Brazil.

Comment: Why so rude? Like it or not, the truth is that "lavandina" is used in the Southern Cone of South America, namely, in Argentina, Uruguay, Chile, Paraguay and Bolivia, as you might care to see here: https://dle.rae.es/lavandina You can check it in the map if you wish. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

«Mancha de cloro». Here in Colombia.